# Android 2.x weird characters

Tags: android, character-encoding, browserstack

I'm doing some mobile testing on browserstack and have begun looking at older devices.
I'm getting a strange character encoding in android 2.x browsers - see below

[image: testing on browserstack, in a android 2 environment]

I cannot figure out what would be causing this

Character encoding?

svgs' as background images? I assumed that if a property declaration isn't understood, that it would fallback or ignore it, for example.

`.logo-dev {
    background-image:url(/images/logos/header-logo-dev-white25px.png); 
    background-image:url(/images/logos/header-logo-dev-white.svg);
}`

or is it a bug in the android emulator?

Has anyone else come across this issue

Comment: Not really sure about the specific issue that you're facing, but in general I do find inconsistencies between the emulator for older versions of Android (2.x) and actual devices running the same Android version. So, you're not alone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, it was in my css reset

`text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;`

It has been removed from my code permanently